# Passing datatable to function in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

As you can see I am trying to pass resultClub (The list) that is returned from the call to resultClubList

The problem is that resultClub is uninitialized outside the /datatable. I want to send the whole list not single values. Is it possible?

```
<h:form>    
<p:dataTable id="averages" var="resultClub" value="#{serviceSeries.resultClubList }" 

             border="1">

                <h:inputHidden id="hiddenID" value="#{resultClub.id}" />

                <p:column id="lastName" sortBy="#{resultClub.lastName}">
                    <f:facet name="header">Efternamn</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{resultClub.lastName}" />
                </p:column>

</p:dataTable>

<h:commandButton action="#{servicePlayer.Average(resultClub)}" value="Uppdatera">
                </h:commandButton>


</h:form>
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do in the back end with the passed list? Can you be clear in your question. Apart from that you can use binding attribute of the datatable binded to a backend bean property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your list inside  `getResultClubList()` method of `serviceSeries` bean.

Ex:

```
getResultClubList(){

    resultClubList.add(someObject);
    ...
    return resultClubList;
}
```